# What happens if you wait 18 hours?

Tags: metal-gear-solid

In Metal Gear Solid 1, what happens if you wait 18 hours which according to Campbell, "Is the deadline for the terrorists demands"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing.

I have previously put well over 20 hours into the game. My second playthrough was a lot shorter, and did have a differant ending;

> In the first playthrough I didn't save Meryl, and in the second playthrough, I did;

However, there was no apparent penalty or reaction to the implicated deadline.

---

As **RenaissanceProgrammer** reminded me, the deadline was a ruse, played on by both sides.

> Both DARPA Chief Anderson and ArmsTech president Keneth Baker die before the terrorists gain access to the nuclaur codes. In fact; They have to trick Snake into arming it, towards the end of the game, under the impression that he is actually disarming it. One can speculate that even the announcement of the deadline was a ruse, used to motivate Solid Snake's infiltration of Shadow Moses, which in turn was controlled in order to infect FOXHOUND with the FoxDie virus.

Comment: Yes, because the deadline was just a ruse, the real goal was for the different parties involved to get their hands on REX or the REX battle data. Campbell was told "24 hours" from Houseman, and Houseman was working on his own to either get the data or kill both Liquid and Solid. Remember that FOXHOUND never actually got the access they needed to launch a nuke. The deadline and the event were all setup by the Patriots and was highly controlled. The deadline was more or less the motivation needed to send Solid Snake into Shadow Moses at the right time.

Comment: That is a good point, @RenaissanceProgrammer. I will add it into my answer.